# How to display labels on x axis?

Tags: r

Here is my .csv file :

```
dateval,links
18/03/2013,100
19/03/2013,200
20/03/2013,300
21/03/2013,400
22/03/2013,500
```

This file is read into an object named date1 and this is the code I'm using to graph the data :

```
g_range <- range(0, date1$links)
plot(date1$links, type="o", col="blue", ylim=g_range,
    axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)
axis(1, xlab=date1$links)
box()
title(main="Additions", col.main="red", font.main=4)
axis(2, las=1, at=50*0:g_range[2])
title(xlab="Date", col.lab=rgb(0,0.5,0))
title(ylab="# Links", col.lab=rgb(0,0.5,0))
```

Here is the generated graph :

[image]

The date values are not being outputted, instead the numbers 1 - 5 are displayed. How can I modify the code so that it generates the date values contained in the .csv file ? I think the problem is with this line : `axis(1, xlab=date1$links)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
axis(1,at=1:5,labels = date1$dateval)
```

So, you'll note that if you look carefully at `?axis` you'll see that there is no `xlab` argument at all, but the second and third arguments are:

> **at** - the points at which tick-marks are to be drawn. Non-finite
>   (infinite, NaN or NA) values are omitted. By default (when NULL)
>   tickmark locations are computed, see ‘Details’ below.
>
> **labels** - this can either be a logical value specifying whether
>   (numerical) annotations are to be made at the tickmarks, or a
>   character or expression vector of labels to be placed at the
>   tickpoints. (Other objects are coerced by as.graphicsAnnot.) If this
>   is not logical, at should also be supplied and of the same length. If
>   labels is of length zero after coercion, it has the same effect as
>   supplying TRUE.

But really maybe you should be doing something more like this:

```
date1$dateval <- as.Date(date1$dateval,format = "%d/%m/%Y")
plot(date1$dateval,date1$links, type="o", col="blue", ylim=g_range, ann=FALSE,axes = FALSE)
axis(1,at=date1$dateval,labels = date1$dateval)
```

But even that is kind of a crude way to handle plotting dates compared to using packages/functions specifically designed for that purpose.

Comment: Beat me to the punch. I would also add that the OP might want to avoid future problems when dealing with unevenly spaced dates by converting `date1$dateval` to a `Date` object. E.g. - using `as.Date(date1$dateval,format="%d/%m/%Y")`

Comment: @joran the amount of dates is dynamic, so the date1 object in above example contains 5 dates & values, but in but it could contain 10 dates etc... instead of using 1:5 is there a parameter value that accommodates this ?

Comment: @user470184 (1) Calculate the number of rows in your data frame. (2) pass to `at` a sequence from 1 to the number of rows in your data frame.

Comment: @joran - or even just do `at=seq_along(date1$dateval)`, assuming the dates are evenly spaced as noted above.

Comment: @thelatemail i used at=1:nrow(date1) this is ok ?

Comment: @user470184 - that's fine - but please take note of joran's last edit about formally making date data a `Date` object.